# Test automation frameworkfor ios using Google's Native Driver

Tags: objective-c, ios, unit-testing, automation

Google recently announced that native driver now has support for IOS as well. I was wondering if any one tried automating the tests using Native driver for ios and any pit falls you encountered?

Currenlty our ios team is using UIA framework for IOS and Android team is using Google's native driver for automating the tests. I was wondering if any one who used both Google's native driver for ios and UIA for ios, to come up with the pros and cons of using both.